Incorrect Decimal Formatting in Dart code
Issue Description
I'm experiencing an issue with formatting Decimal values in Dart.
I have the following code snippet:
import 'package:decimal/Decimal.dart';

Decimal formatDecimal(Decimal value) {
  String formattedString = value.toStringAsFixed(2);
  return Decimal.parse(formattedString);
}

void main() {
  Decimal decimalValue = Decimal.parse('8');
  Decimal formattedValue = formatDecimal(decimalValue);
  
  print(formattedValue); // Output: 8
}

The expected output of the print statement is 8.00 in Decimal format, but the actual output is 8. It seems that the formatting is not being applied correctly.
Could someone please advise on how to correctly format the Decimal value 8 to 8.00 in Dart?
Thank you.

formattedValue is not a formatted value and is just a value that you have potentially reduced the precision of. Numerically 8.00 is exactly the same as 8. formatDecimal should just be returning the value of formattedString.

According to the documentation, you can use the intl package to apply a formatter to your value:
import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';
import 'package:decimal/intl.dart';

main() {
  var value = Decimal.parse('1234.56');
  var formatter = NumberFormat.decimalPattern('en-US');
  print(formatter.format(DecimalIntl(value)));
}

Edit: I whipped up your example code and fixed the issue:
import 'package:decimal/Decimal.dart';

String formatDecimal(Decimal value) {
  String formattedString = value.toStringAsPrecision(3);
  return formattedString;
}

void main() {
  Decimal decimalValue = Decimal.parse('8');
  String formattedValue = formatDecimal(decimalValue);

  print(formattedValue); // Output: 8.00
}


formatter.format(DecimalIntl(value))
returnType String but I want a Decimal format Value
example
Decimal decimalValue = Decimal.parse('8');
return value 8.00 in  Decimal Type

I whipped up a test project and fixed your code. I've updated my answer to reflect that change.

Try now
import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';

Decimal formatDecimal(Decimal value) {
  String formattedString = value.toStringAsFixed(2);
  
  // Append trailing zeros if necessary
  if (!formattedString.contains('.')) {
    formattedString += '.00';
  } else if (formattedString.endsWith('.')) {
    formattedString += '00';
  } else if (formattedString.endsWith('.0')) {
    formattedString += '0';
  }
  
  return Decimal.parse(formattedString);
}

void main() {
  Decimal decimalValue = Decimal.parse('8');
  Decimal formattedValue = formatDecimal(decimalValue);
  
  print(formattedValue); // Output: 8.00
}

